# How to call a method on a local variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, scope

Probably a stupid question but I was following along [this article](https://www.icelab.com.au/notes/functional-command-objects-in-ruby/) and came across a bit of code I couldn't quite grasp. Here it is:

```
class CreateArticle
  attr_reader :validate_article, :persist_article

  def initialize(validate_article, persist_article)
    @validate_article = validate_article
    @persist_article = persist_article
  end

  def call(params)
    result = validate_article.call(params)

    if result.success?
      persist_article.call(params)
    end
  end
end
```

More specifically, the problematic line is this:

```
if result.success?
```

Here's my problem with it: where did the `success?` method come from? It's not default in Ruby, and `result` is a local variable, so it should be nearby. But even if it's just omitted in the code sample, where would it have to be defined for that line to work? Everywhere I tried to define it just gave me an 'undefined method' error.

For example, I tried to define it both in the `CreateArticle` class and in the (only alluded to) `ValidateArticle` class, the obvious culprits, but no dice.

**Update:**

The reason I ask is not so much about what `success?` does as it is because I'm interested in using the *pattern* in my code. So, for example, my version of the `success?` method could be just checking whether a value got updated, or an item was inserted into an array. For example, let's say it's just this:

```
def success? # or self.success?
  return true
end
```

Problem is, I can find no place where I can put this that works. I even created a module just for it and `include`d it into the class, and still it doesn't work (it just returns 'undefined method'). So I'm still at a loss as to where I would have to define such a method so that it would work the way it looks like it should.

Answer (score 1):

Actually  `. success?`  **is** a built in ruby method. Check  [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process/Status.html#method-i-success-3F). What it actually does is checking Stat and returns a boolean.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken, but I looked it up. Apparently it's related to spawning multiple Processes. Thanks.

Comment: It really was! I fixed it now in case somebody else is searching for it

Comment: How do you know that `validate_article.call(params).ancestors.include?(Process::Status) #=> true`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a method that comes with rails. It checks.for a server response with a 200 code. If it gets a 200 code it returns true else it returns false. Read the rails API docs about it... https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveResource/Response/success%3F

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. And do you know if it's automatically available application-wide?

Comment: Ideally it would be used in the model. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base

Comment: U can see on that last link that API responses are checked a little differently.

Comment: It could be, I'm not sure. Thing is, I'm interested in using the pattern in my code. So, for example, my version of the `success?` method could be just checking whether a value got updated, or an item was inserted into an array. For example, let's say it's just this: `def self.success?; return true; end`. Problem is, I can find no place where I can put this that works. I even created a module and included it into the class, and still it doesn't work. So I'm still at a loss as to where I would have to define such a method so that it *would* work.

Comment: You can use `result.method(:success?)` to see where it's defined. Also check `result.class`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. However, in this specific case, I have no access to the actual code, just the excerpt on the blog post.

Comment: Further to @maxpleaner's comment, you can write `result.method(:success?).owner` to see where the method is defined, but if you look closely at the return value of `result.method(:success?)` it also gives the owner when it is not the object's class. For example, `1.method(:angle).owner #=> Numeric`,  `1.method(:angle) #=> #<Method: Integer(Numeric)#angle>`. By contrast,  consider the following example where the instance method is defined on the object's class: `1.method(:+).owner #=> Integer`; `1.method(:+) #=> #<Method: Integer#+>`.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging around the blog and from what I found I suspect that the code is probably making use of the [dry-monads gem](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-monads/result/):

> You can explicitly check the type by calling `failure?` or `success?` on a monadic value.

It's not explicit in the code excerpt but it's the only thing that makes sense.